# Onde nasceu a expressão: "No São Martinho mata o porquinho e semeia o cebolinho"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, proverbios

> No São Martinho mata o porquinho e semeia o cebolinho.

Onde nasceu esta expressão?

Refere-se a que hemisfério?

Cebolinho vem de cebolas?

Comment: Tens contexto? Isto é: onde ouviste ou leste a expressão? E tentaste procurar "cebolinho" num dicionário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há muitos provérbios com o São Martinho ([ver aqui](https://lerparacrer.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/proverbios-sobre-o-sao-martinho/)), é de facto um santo popular e o sufixo '**inho**' é dado a rimas, como neste caso a rima com cebol**inho**.

A razão de matar o porquinho é a festa de São Martinho ser em Novembro, e portanto no início do inverno. As razões são múltiplas:

- Nas regiões de serra e montanha, por o frio ser muito, convém matar os porcos pequenos pois podem de facto morrer de frio (para quem é de regiões mais amenas esta noção pode parecer estranha).
- O inverno é a altura do ano em que a produção agrícola se torna escassa, portanto os animais são engordados durante o verão com excedentes agrícolas para serem abatidos antes de inverno.
- Antes de haver frigoríficos usavam-se salgadeiras para conservar a carne. No caso do porco faz sentido matá-lo no princípio do inverno para encher a salgadeira e preparar chouriças para o fumeiro.

Quanto ao cebolinho pode ser cultivado o ano todo, mas requer abundância de água e um sólo bem drenado. A necessidade de água sugere de facto Outono/Inverno serem alturas mais indicadas para o seu cúltivo, dependendo também da precipitação nessa zona do país, díria que a expressão será originária da região do Tejo e sul.

Um bom artigo sobre [ervas aromáticas](https://www.saberviver.pt/comida/nutricao/beneficios-ervas-aromaticas/).

Comment: O São Martinho dos provérbios não é o santo, é o dia em si; ou aquele período. O santo popular não vem ao caso.

Comment: Os santos vêm sempre ao caso @ANeves !! Sempre! Ohh São Bonifácio de Mogúncia, dai-me paciência!

Comment: «Um acontecimento-chave da sua vida ocorreu em 723, quando derrubou o carvalho sagrado dedicado ao deus Thor, perto da moderna cidade de Fritzlar, no norte do Hesse, e construiu uma pequena capela a partir da sua madeira (...)» ... que néscio, esse tal "santo bem-fazente de Mainz".

Comment: Oh @ANeves o que disseste constitui "crude language" que é contra o CoC, e tb não é gentil. Quero ser cordial, se fizeres um estudo do "fenômeno religioso" (no sentido da antropolgia, seja) verás que nesta matéria o insulto nunca é´correcto. Também em linguística, no séc.VIII o Português não existia. Do Althochdeutsche os textos conhecidos, são na maioria eclesiáticos, escritos em sucessão da obra do dito santo. O fim da "idade das trevas" na Europa, está ligada ao abate desse carvalho.

Comment: Não existe a palavra "crude" no CoC. Eu edito para tirar a palavra grosseira, mas a frase fica exatamente igual tanto em tom como em conteúdo... ‍♀️ Acho que temos uma visão profundamente diferente da linguagem.

Comment: E do mundo também parecemos ter uma visão profundamente diferente. Pode ser que os talibans tragam o fim da "idade das trevas" no Médio Oriente, com o derrube dos [Budas de Bamyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhas_of_Bamyan); lá para 2500 ou 2700. Entretanto, eu vou chorando a sua perda.

Comment: Bom @ANeves, o nosso forte é: não nos recusarmos ao diálogo. São Bonifácio não cortou o carvalho - sozinho, teria sobrevivido? Essa história, é "O detalhe" em jeito de fábula -a ser interpretado- por entre factos históricos. Ele é a figura, que representa a vontade dos que o rodeavam - opondo-se, precisamente, à coerção pagã. A escolha desse iconoclasmo, é em grau mínimo, inóquo - muito diferente de outros iconoclasmos. Nesta medida foi a tua comparação descabida. O estudo do séc.XX mostra ser o diálogo entre fés construtor da paz - tanto sim, é um facto.

Comment: @ANeves Tenhamos, juntos, uma visão mais erudita da hagiografia. Acho ser preciso olhar para São Maurício - para entendermos o significado do gesto atribuído a São Bonifácio. Em continuidade do que foi a obra de São Bento de Núrsia (esta sim, claramente documentada). A história do humanismo na Europa, não pode ser escrita sem referir o beneditinos.